# Performance Tomcat 7 vs Glassfish 3

Tags: performance, servlets, tomcat7, neo4j, glassfish-3

I have a simple JSP/Servlet maven application which allows a user to upload an archive file. The application will then unzip the archive which contains XML files, and parse them using basic SAX parsing. It will generate an in-memory representation of these files, and write them to a Neo4J Graph Database, currently in embedded mode.

During development, I used a GlassFish v3 but with production in sight, the request has been made to move from Glassfish to Tomcat and so I did. Apart from a few small issues with Tomcat forcing me to add JSF dependencies despite the fact that I'm not using any JSF, there is one big issue I have with Tomcat atm.

The largest testfile I have takes about 8 seconds to upload and parse on glassfish v3. After that, it takes about 2 seconds less, due to the fact that I don't clean up the uploaded file (yet).

The same file on Tomcat7 takes about 90 seconds to upload and parse the first time. The other times it takes about 20 seconds less, presumably because of the same reason.

In any case, there's a difference in performance of factor 10. I'm a little bit surprised, since I thought that using Tomcat would actually increase the speed due to it being more lightweight than Glassfish, since I'm not really using the advanced functionalities provided by Glassfish.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and what did you do to resolve this? Is this even resolvable, or is it due to the way that Tomcat works...

**EDIT: The difference appears to be in the code section that is responsible for writing the in-memory representation of the files to the actual database... No idea why though...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a comparison of Tomcat with Glassfish but yes, the new Glassfish versions are very light weight and have very good performance. I have experienced the same. I guess running an application server instead of a Tomcat is no more huge administration and hardware waste (and you can use light weight EJB 3 and 3.1 if you like). Glassfish installations can be very small in size if you only select the necessary modules.

Check this page. It compares Jboss, Glassfish and Resin

http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-ee-6-server-comparison.html

And this one compares Glassfish 3.1 and Jboss 6 & 7.

http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/10/jboss-as-7-catching-up-with-java-ee-6.html